# How does ServicePointManager.ReusePort and SO_REUSE_UNICASTPORT alleviate ephemeral port exhaustion?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, .net-4.6, windows-server-2016

Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016 introduced the `SO_REUSE_UNICASTPORT` socket option. It was made available for use in .NET starting from version 4.6 via the `ServicePointManager.ReusePort` static property. I'm suffering from ephemeral port exhaustion on a .NET application during very high loads (many concurrent outgoing requests via `HttpClient`), and I am considering using this option to deal with it. I'm aware of other ways to deal with the problem (such as editing the Windows Registry to modify the max number of ephemeral ports or shortening TIME_WAIT), but I'd like to fully under this solution too.

The documentation for [`ServicePointManager.ReusePort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.reuseport.aspx) is very minimal:

> Setting this property value to true causes all outbound TCP connections from HttpWebRequest to use the native socket option SO_REUSE_UNICASTPORT on the socket. This causes the underlying outgoing ports to be shared. This is useful for scenarios where a large number of outgoing connections are made in a short time, and the app risks running out of ports.

Looking at the documentation for [`SO_REUSE_UNICASTPORT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740532.aspx) doesn't provide any additional insights:

> When set, allow ephemeral port reuse for Winsock API connection functions which require an explicit bind, such as ConnectEx. Note that connection functions with an implicit bind (such as connect without an explicit bind) have this option set by default. Use this option instead of SO_PORT_SCALABILITY on platforms where both are available.

I couldn't find any explanation on the web as to how exactly this "ephemeral port reuse" is achieved, how exactly it works on a technical level, and how well it reduces the risk of ephemeral port exhaustion. How much of an improvement can I expect? Using this feature, how can I calculate a new limit for my application? Are there any downsides to enabling this?

This is all shrouded in mystery and I'd love it if someone can explain this new mechanism and its implications.

Comment: can you share what logs or counters you looked at that suggested port exhaustion was happening on your application?

Comment: @AnirudhGoel: We got the dreaded `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted` exception, and running `nestat -a -o` on the machine that has that exception showed numerous ephemeral ports in use.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

TCP connection is uniquely identified by (local IP, local port, remote IP, remote port). That means it's perfectly possible to use the same (local IP, local port) pair for multiple sockets connecting to different remote endpoints. Suppose you want to make http request to "site1.com" and "site2.com". You are using sockets with the following code:

```
using (var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)) {                
    socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("some local ip"), 45455));
    socket.Connect(server, port);
    socket.Send(someBytes);
    // ...
}
```

So you are binding socket to specific local endpoint with port 45455. If you now try to do that concurrently to make requests to "site1.com" and "site2.com" you will get "an address already in use" exception.

But if you add `ReuseAddress` option (note that it's not option your question is about) before binding:

```
socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
```

You will be able to bind to sockets to the same local (ip, port) and you will see in netstat two ESTABLISHED connections.

All of the above is to show that in theory nothing prevents one to reuse even ephemeral port to make multiple connections to **different** remote endpoints. But, when you bind to ephemeral port (`0`) - it is not yet known to which remote endpoint you are going to connect. Suppose all ephemeral ports are in use and you are binding to 0. OS provides you some port for reuse during bind phase, there is one socket using this port already connected to "site1.com". You are trying to connect to "site1.com" too and that fails (because all 4 values identifying tcp connection are the same for both sockets).

What `SO_REUSE_UNICASTPORT` does is it delays choosing ephemeral port when you bind to 0 until actual connection phase (`Connect()` call for example). At this phase (unlike bind) you already know local ip, remote ip, remote port you are going to connect to, and you need to choose ephemeral port. Suppose all ports are in use. Now, instead of choosing some random port for reuse (and potentially fail later on connect) you can choose port which is connected to **different** remote endpoint (different from what current socket is trying to connect to).

You can confirm this for example at this [MS support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3014399/various-network-and-computer-issues-occur-when-tcp-ephemeral-ports-are):

> SO_REUSE_UNICASTPORT
>
> For a connection scenario to be implemented, the socket option must be
>   set before binding a socket. This option instructs the system to
>   postpone port allocation until connection time when the 4-tuple
>   (quadruple) for the connection is known.

Note that `SO_REUSE_UNICASTPORT` only has effect on explicit bindings (as stated in your question quote, but still worth repeating). If you bind implicitly (such as when you just `Connect()` without binding) - this option is already set by default (where supported of course).

About which effect this has on your particular application. First from the above it should be clear that if your application makes ton of requests to the same remote endpoint (to the same http server for example) - this option will have no effect. If you make a lot of requests to different endpoints though - it should help to prevent ports exhaustion. Still effect of `ServicePointManager.ReusePort` itself depends on how `HttpClient` works with sockets internally I guess. If it just `Connect()` without explicit binding - this option should be enabled (on supported systems) by default, so setting `ServicePointManager.ReusePort` to `true` will not have additional effect, otherwise it will. Since you don't know (and should not rely on) its internal implementation its worth enabling `ServicePointManager.ReusePort` in your particular scenario.

You can also perform tests with this option on\off by limiting range of ephemeral ports (with command like `netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport tcp`) to some small amounts and see how it goes.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, especially explaining the different effects between making calls to the same set of servers versus many different servers. In our case, the issue was that our .NET application was acting as an API gateway that sometimes forwarded the call to another system (as-is). When the other system had periods of slowness, the number of concurrent calls to the same set of servers grew because the response time increased yet incoming traffic remained constant, eventually leading to port exhaustion. So it seems that in this case, `ServicePointManager.ReusePort` won't help us.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek yes seems so. In this case I'd suggest to add more ip addresses (interfaces) to your system, because then you will have (number of ips * dynamic port range) ephemeral ports to use (in this case also take a look at SO_PORT_SCALABILITY, though as I understand SO_REUSE_UNICASTPORT already implies SO_PORT_SCALABILITY).

Comment: Good suggestion. In addition to adding IPs to the source machines, adding more IP addresses for the target system might also help when used with SO_REUSE_UNICASTPORT because there will be more destination IPs, so more reuse potential on each connection. BTW, I haven't found a way to use SO_PORT_SCALABILITY in .NET, particularly with high-level network APIs like `HttpClient` (or even `HttpWebRequest`). Do you know of a way?

Comment: @AllonGuralnek nope I'm not aware how (and if at all possible) to get to the underlying socket from `HttpClient` or `HttpWebRequest`. But documentation says "use SO_REUSE_UNICASTPORT instead of  SO_PORT_SCALABILITY if possible", which suggests that former already implies latter, so you can just use `ServicePointManager.ReusePort` to achieve this.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek but if you have socket in hand, I think you can set this option like that: `socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, (SocketOptionName) 0x3006, true);` `SocketOptionName` does not contain predefined value for that, but after all enum is just a number in .NET, so you can use any number, even that which does not have predefined value in enum itself. Code that uses enum might have a check with `Enum.IsDefined` to check if number really has corresponding  enum value, but it's not the case for socket options - it is passed as is to native api.

Comment: Unfortunately, using sockets is not an option for us, as we need application-wide HTTP connection reuse and pipelining, which is provided by `ServicePointManager`, only if using high-level HTTP APIs and not sockets. I haven't found a way to tell the underlying sockets of those APIs to use certain options.